# Force marginnote to change page

Tags: marginnote

Got my code here

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}
Some text
\marginnote{\lipsum[1-4]}

\end{document}
```

How can I avoid marginnote to go down beyond the red line in the picture?
P.S: Regarding the previous question, I'm sorry, I badly explained myself, @egreg & @Cristian, thanks a lot for your answer! 
[image]

Comment: marginnote notes don't split over a page so it's probably unreasonable to put that much text into one, there is however a voffset optional argument so you could move it up.

Comment: I don't follow. Change page? Shall it shift to another page? `\marginnote`  does not split/break across pages as @DavidCarlisle already noted

Comment: Yes, because in my text a very large amount of marginnote are often shifted up and down, and sometimes this marginnote goes down beyond the red line, I wanted to avoid that

Comment: @Francesco: The `\marginnote` can not be automatically shifted to another page. If there's much more content than fits the marginnote vertical size, reduce either the content or increase the margins. I'll delete my answer since it's completely useless since you changed the question

Comment: I was afraid that there would not be a way to do this. Thanks however!

Comment: You can try the [`marginfix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/marginfix) package.

Answer (score 1):

`\marginnote` places the top of the margin note level with the word it is next to. In your example you're typesetting five `\lipsum` paragraphs and then issuing `\marginnote`. The anchor to `\marginnote` is thus *after* all five paragraphs.

A better example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}

A word\marginnote{A margin note} \lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]